# C: segmentation fault sometimes?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Hello fellow Stackoverflowers!

Why does my code below throw a Segmentation fault only sometimes (i.e. 1/10 times)?

Console:

Input a string

racecar

Segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char string_buffer[21];
   int i, length;
   int flag = 0;

   print f("Input a string\n");
   scanf("%20s", string_buffer);

   length = strlen(string_buffer);

   for(i=0; i < length; i++) {
      if(string_buffer[i] != string_buffer[length-i-1]) {
         flag = 1;
         break;
      }
   }

   if(flag) {
      printf("%sNot a Palindrome.\n");
   }
   else {
      printf("%sPalindrome.\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem but use `scanf("%20s%n", string_buffer, &length);` instead of `strlen()`.

Comment: Very likely because it invoked undefined behaviour 10/10 times ...

Comment: I would advice you to use fgets or getline instead of a scanf, by the way you are experiencing this problem because of the last two printf as pointed out by iharob

Answer (score 2):

Your `printf()` statements expect a `char *` pointer and you are not passing one. That invokes undefined behavior.

Change this

```
if(flag) {
   printf("%sNot a Palindrome.\n");
}
else {
   printf("%sPalindrome.\n");
}
```

to

```
if (flag == 1) 
   printf("`%s' IS NOT a Palindrome.\n", string_buffer);
else 
   printf("`%s' IS a Palindrome.\n", string_buffer);
```

If you enable compiler warnings you should be warned about this.

This is an improved version of your code with the problem decribed above fixed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string_buffer[21];
    int flag = 0;
    int length;

    if (scanf("%20s%n", string_buffer, &length) != 1)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0 ; ((flag == 0) && (i < length)) ; ++i)
        flag = (string_buffer[i] != string_buffer[length - i - 1]);
    if (flag == 1)
        printf("`%s' IS NOT a Palindrome.\n", string_buffer);
    else
        printf("`%s' IS a Palindrome.\n", string_buffer);
    return 0;
}
```